VBA MATCH function only working when value to be matched is hard coded
I cannot get my VBA MATCH function below to work. I need the VBA to take a week number from a reference sheet (which the VBA does successfully), search for that week number in the columns of a search sheet, and then return the column number to the reference sheet. I can only get the MATCH function to work if I hard code the week number (e.g. "42").
Thanks in advance for your help.
The code I've been trying to make work is as below:
Sub Example()
    
    WeekNumber = Worksheets("Reference sheet").Range("E1")
    
    TargetColumn = Application.Match(WeekNumber, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search sheet").Range("3:3"), 0)
    
    Worksheets("Reference sheet").Range("H9").Value = TargetColumn
    
End Sub

I have also tried the below in the TargetColumn line:
TargetColumn = Application.Match(Worksheets("Reference sheet").Range("E1").Value, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search shheet").Range("3:3"), 0)

The 'WeekNumber' is 42. If I try the below, the function works perfectly (it returns column number 46):
TargetColumn = Application.Match("42", ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search sheet").Range("3:3"), 0)

How can I get this to work without hard coding the match value? Thanks in advance for your help.

"42" is not the same as 42.

Thanks for your comment - I'm aware that this is probably the issue, however I can't seem to solve it. How can I get 42 to be read as "42", or how can 42 be a matchable value (on this note, I tried making sure that 42 is stored as a number in the search sheet - didn't seem to solve anything)?

WeekNumber = Worksheets("Reference sheet").Range("E1") you haven't declared WeekNumber as any particular type, so that's the starting point for fixing your issue.  If the data you're matching against is stored as whole numbers on the worksheet then declare Dim WeekNumber As Long.   If the sheet values are stored as Text then Dim WeekNumber As String  Seems like matching against a hard-coded "42" works, so your data seems to be "Text" ...

Use of Find() may also be benefitial, as opposed to using the worksheet function Match().  In both cases you should have error handling if no match or range if found.

Using Application.Match
A Quick Fix (Not Recommended)
Sub Example()
    With ActiveWorkbook
        WeekText = CStr(.Sheets("Reference sheet").Range("E1").Value)
        TargetColumn = Application.Match(WeekText, .Sheets("Search sheet").Rows(3), 0)
        .Sheets("Reference sheet").Range("H9").Value = TargetColumn
    End With
End Sub

Step By Step (Recommended)
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateHeaderColumn()
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it's not, reference the workbook by name or use 'ActiveWorkbook'.
    
    ' Reference the source objects.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Search sheet")
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Rows(3) ' lookup
    ' Contains the week numbers as text.
    
    ' Reference the destination objects.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Reference sheet")
    Dim dlcell As Range: Set dlcell = dws.Range("E1") ' lookup
    Dim drcell As Range: Set drcell = dws.Range("H9") ' return
    
    ' Store the week number (converted to a string) in a string variable.
    Dim dlWeek As String: dlWeek = CStr(dlcell.Value)
    ' If the week number from 1 to 9 have a leading 0,
    ' use 'dlWeek = Format(CStr(dlcell.Value),"00")'.
    
    ' Attempt to retrieve the destination column, the left-most column
    ' containing the week (as string).
    Dim drColumn As Variant: drColumn = Application.Match(dlWeek, slrg, 0)
    
    ' If the week is not found, display a message box and exit.
    If IsError(drColumn) Then
        MsgBox "Week " & dlWeek & " was not found in the range ""'" _
            & sws.Name & "'!" & slrg.Address(0, 0) & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If the week is found, write its column to the destination return cell.
    drcell.Value = drColumn
    
End Sub

